# Referring to the DOJO Javascript file

Tags: dojo

I am new to DOJO. I have one question regarding the dojo framework .

Is there any difference in referring to the DOJO js file in either cases

First case:

```
<script src="dojo.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
        </script>
```

Second case:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
        </script>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The first case calls the `dojo.js` JavaScript file (core Dojo library) from a path relative to the web server's document root. In other words, it is a local installation (local to the server) of the Dojo libraries.

The second calls the core Dojo library file from an external source, in this case the Google APIs library.  It includes the `.xd` as part of its filename to indicate that this particular build of the Dojo toolkit [supports cross-domain loading](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/cross-domain.html)

A benefit of installing the Dojo toolkit libraries locally is that you can customize your build to include only the components you need, possibly resulting in a much leaner set of JavaScript files for your users to download.

A benefit of using a 3rd party like Google APIs is that they are commonly used and therefore many users may already have the core files in their browser caches, eliminating the need to download them at all when accessing your web application.  The overall file download size is likely to be larger than a custom build you put together yourself though.  A service like Google APIs makes several different versions of the Dojo toolkit available for use (the one above is using 1.6), in case you have specific version needs for your application.  In contrast, you would need to maintain local installations of multiple versions yourself if you had differing needs for your applications.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that in cross-domain builds modules are loaded asynchronously so you need to wrap any code that uses the library in a dojo.ready. (This will be less of an issue in the new 1.7+ module system though)

Comment: @missingno: I wouldn't call it any less of an issue in 1.7 (not that I call it an "issue" to begin with ;) ). However, if you are alluding to the AMD format support added in 1.7, then you might say it'll become a bit more natural to code asynchronously.  Doesn't change the fact that xd usage of dojo is async (and if I'm not mistaken, in same-domain cases, the loader still defaults to synchronous operation, for backwards-compatibility).